# How to compare 3d arrays of different length along one dimension?

Tags: r, arrays, linear-interpolation, dimensionality-reduction

I want to compare the median of 3d arrays along the second dimension (by index step), but the length of different arrays are usually different.

For example (same length):

```
dat1 <- array(seq(1,   1000), c(100, 70, 100))
dat2 <- array(seq(500, 1500), c(100, 70, 100))

data <- tibble(step = seq(1, length(dat1[1,,1])), 
               md1 = apply(dat1, 2, median), 
               md2 = apply(dat2, 2, median)) %>% 
    gather(md1, md2, key = "dat", value = "median") 

ggplot(data, aes(step, median, color = dat)) + 
    geom_line()
```

[image]

But how to compare `dat1` with different length `dat3` like this:

```
dat3 <- array(seq(300, 1200), c(100, 55, 100))
```

I want to bin arrays along the second dimension by every 5% step first, then compare the median of every bin. Is there a method to do this?

Or any suggestions to compare different length 3d arrays? Or is extracting the median of every index then interpolate values to same length a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you update what/how the result should look like, and/or a naive way of achieving this? I didn't fully understand.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @GioraSimchoni. I updated the question.